# Get shell output from python script using QProcess

Tags: python, stdout, pyqt6, pagekite

I am writing a program with PyQT6 to update a progress bar based on output of the pagekite.py file, I'm using QProcess to call the script and a function to handle the output, but the output from the shell when i run the file looks like this:

```
>>> Hello! This is pagekite.py v1.5.2.201011.                   [CTRL+C = Stop]
    Connecting to front-end relay 00.00.000.00:000 ...
     - Relay supports 10 protocols on 23 public ports.
     - Raw TCP/IP (HTTP proxied) kites are available.
     - To enable more logging, add option: --logfile=/path/to/logfile
~<> Flying localhost:80 as https://test.pagekite.me/
 << pagekite.py [exiting]  Good-bye!
```

But when i get the output of the stdout of QProcess it look like this:

```
ts=63837a93; t=2022-11-27T14:56:19; ll=7; connect=000.000.00.000:000

ts=63837a94; t=2022-11-27T14:56:20; ll=8; FE=000.000.00.000:000; err=Rejected; proto=http; reason=quota; domain=test.pagekite.me; id=s2
ts=63837a94; t=2022-11-27T14:56:20; ll=9; FE=000.000.00.000:000; ports=79,80,443, ...; protocols=http,http2,http3,https,websocket,irc,finger,httpfinger,raw; raw_ports=virtual

ts=63837a94; t=2022-11-27T14:56:20; ll=a; wrote=484; wbps=114; read=992; eof=1; id=s2

ts=63837a9e; t=2022-11-27T14:56:30; ll=b; FE=000.000.00.000:000; http_ping_ms=693; win=2; uuid=222cf21b34cfd5bed67bace00000d00000dafff0; unbiased_ms=643

ts=63837ab9; t=2022-11-27T14:56:57; ll=c; FE=000.000.00.000:000; http_ping_ms=693; win=2; uuid=222cf21b34cfd5bed67bace00000d00000dafff0; unbiased_ms=64
```

Here is the code of the program:

```
import time
import sys
from PyQt6.QtCore import QThread, QProcess
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QDialog,
    QDialogButtonBox,
    QFormLayout,
    QLineEdit,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QPushButton,
    QLabel,
    QProgressBar,
)

class ProgressBar(QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setMaximum(100)
        self._active = False
        self.setTextVisible(False)

    def setBar(self, i):
        self.setValue(i)

    def changeColor(self, color):
        css = """
            ::chunk {{
                background: {0};
            }}
        """.format(color)
        self.setStyleSheet(css)

class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None)
        self.setWindowTitle("QDialog")

        dialogLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        formLayout = QFormLayout()
        confBtn = QPushButton('Configurações')
        self.ligarBtn = QPushButton('Iniciar o aplicativo')
        statusLbl = QLabel('Desligado')
        self.ligado = False
        formLayout.addRow(confBtn)
        formLayout.addRow(self.ligarBtn)
        formLayout.addRow("Status: ", statusLbl)
        dialogLayout.addLayout(formLayout)
        self.connBar = ProgressBar()
        self.connBar.setBar(4)
        self.connBar.changeColor('gray')
        buttons = QDialogButtonBox()
        buttons.addButton('Fechar', QDialogButtonBox.ButtonRole.ActionRole)
        dialogLayout.addWidget(self.connBar)
        self.ligarBtn.clicked.connect(self.iniciaPageKite)
        self.setLayout(dialogLayout)
        self.show()
        y, x = self.geometry().height(), self.geometry().width()
        self.setFixedSize(x, y)
    
    def iniciaPageKite(self):
        self.prcs = QProcess()
        self.prcs.start('py', ['-2.7', 'pagekite.py', '80', 'test.pagekite.me'])
        self.prcs.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.pgktOutputHandler)
        self.prcs.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.pgktErrorHandler)

    def defPrgBarPrg(self, val):
        self.connBar.setBar(val)

    def defPrgBarClr(self, clr):
        self.connBar.changeColor(clr)

    def pgktOutputHandler(self):
        res = self.prcs.readAllStandardOutput()
        resc = bytes(res).decode('utf-8')
        print(resc)

    def pgktErrorHandler(self):
        err = self.prcs.readAllStandardError()
        errc = bytes(err).decode('utf-8')
        print(errc)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    app.exec()
    sys.exit()
```

informations:

- python 3.11
- windows 11
- python 2.7 to pagekite
- PyQt**6**

Sorry for any error or missing information.

Comment: You seem to be connecting *again* `readyReadStandardOutput`, rather than using `readyReadStandardError` for `pgktErrorHandler`.

Comment: @musicamante Yep, my bad, already corrected it, thank you, but it still giving the same result

Comment: That's probably because by default uses buffers for stdout and stderr. I don't know what is your `py` command, but if you can add *python* command line arguments to that, try using the [`-u` flag](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u).

Comment: @musicamante the py is to use a specific version of python, in this case 2.7